# Yii 2.0 Widget element options

Tags: php, html, tags, yii2, yii-widgets

So I have a widget of listView that displays list of text

```
echo Menu::widget([
                   'options' => ['class'=>'nav navbar-nav side-nav'], 
                   'items'   => [
                       ['label' =>'Dashboard', ],
                       ['label' => 'Products'],
                   ]
                ]);
```

When I open browser , the result is :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
   <li>Dashboard</li>
   <li>Products</li>
</ul>
```

How do I add html element inside the `<li>` like below :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
     <li><i class='fap fap-dashboard'>Dashboard</i></li>
     <li><b class='fap fap-product'>Products</b></li>
 </ul>
```

by using widget ?

I have tried putting another item element beside label, but it instead created another `<ul>` element, and I also tried using 'options' beside label, and it instead change the `li` attribute (not creating inside it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reach you goal you need set `encodeLabels` property to `false` ([see](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/Menu.php#L108)). Code like this(it is work code):

```
 Menu::widget([
                'options' => ['class'=>'nav navbar-nav side-nav', 'format' => 'raw'],
                'encodeLabels' => false,
                'items'   => [
                    ['label' => Html::tag('i', 'Dashboard',['class' => 'fap fap-dashboard'])],
                    ['label' => Html::tag('b', 'Products',['class' => 'fap fap-product'])],
                ]
            ]);
```

Comment: So the encodeLabels property is what I missed apparently.. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

this might work-

```
echo Menu::widget([
           'options' => ['class'=>'nav navbar-nav side-nav'], 
           'items'   => [
               ['label' =>'<i class="fap fap-dashboard">Dashboard</i>',"encode"=>false, ],
               ['label' =>'<b class="fap fap-product">Products</b>',"encode"=>false],
           ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Not best practice use html in label. Use `Html` class for generate html code.